# How can I determine the whether rank is user or admin? - Express and Sessions

Tags: mongodb, session, express

I'm working with express-session and mongoose. In my user schema i've got rank key value-pair which is rank: 'admin'/'mod'/'user'

Now how Can I determine the wether rank user have? My session looks like this:

```
app.use(session({
secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'as54v88vrh7e5a9',
store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.mongoose.connections[0],
    ttl: (1*60*60)
}),
cookie: {
    path: '/',
    maxAge: 3600000 //60 min
},
secure: true,
httpOnly: true,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
name: "ID"
}));
```

I can access to session in every req by 'user'. If user = true then we have a session with logged user. I was thinking about using IF CONDITION but I cant compare two arguments with handlebars.

All comes to determine which user have access to f.e admin panel and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had to come up with the answer myself since nobody answer.

Can I do it like this? Is this safe?

```
    function requireAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.json({
            "Error": "You need to log in."
        })
    } else {
        if (req.user.rank !== 'admin') {
            res.json({
                "Error": "You don't have access."
            })
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}
```